# How to calculate a correlation table using the shortest lifespan per pair instead of per universe?

Tags: r, matrix, correlation

The below R-code calculates a correlation matrix and writes it to CSV using the lifespan of the youngest asset in the universe, here EEM.
How do I modify the code for using the shortest lifespan for each asset pair?

```
require(quantmod)
require(PerformanceAnalytics)

symbols <- c("DBC", "EEM", "EFA", "GLD", "IWM", "IYR", "SPY", "TLT")
getSymbols(symbols, from="1900-01-01")

prices <- list()
for(i in 1:length(symbols))
{
    prices[[i]] <- Ad(get(symbols[i]))
}
prices <- do.call(cbind, prices)
colnames(prices) <- gsub("\\.[A-z]*", "", colnames(prices))

returns <- Return.calculate(prices)
returns <- na.omit(returns)

result <- table.Correlation(returns, returns)
result <- result[,1]

corMatrix <- matrix(result, nrow=length(symbols), ncol=length(symbols), byrow=T)
corMatrix <- round(corMatrix, digits=2)

dimnames(corMatrix) = list(colnames(prices), colnames(prices))

write.csv(corMatrix, file="CorrelationTable.csv")

print(corMatrix)
```

[Edit:]

To clarify the pair wise approach:

- use EEM's lifespan for the DBC:EEM pair, since EEM was later introduced than DBC
- use TLT's lifespan for the SPY:TLT pair, since TLT was later introduced than SPY

Lifespan: the number of trading days (data points) since the asset's inception date, i.e. EEM was introduced on Feb 6, 2006.

To be more precise: since correlations are calculated for daily returns, the calculation period should be length - 1

Return: today's adjusted close divided by yesterday's adjusted close.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more explanation about the terms you're using? Maybe narrate the code a little more, so that we can follow.

Comment: Some clarification of terms added.